# Problems loading JSON code in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, websocket

I've been tyring to figure out how to load JSON objects in Python.

I'm able to send a JSON string to the server, but there it fails.

This is what I'm sending through a websocket with JavaScript:

```
ws.send('{"test":"test"}');
```

The server receives it without a problem, but can't validate it:

```
{"test":"test"}
This is not a JSON object!
```

Which comes forth from this code:

```
                    try:
                        data = data[:-1]
                        json.loads(data)
                    except ValueError:
                        print 'This is not a JSON object!'
                    else:
                        print ('JSON found!')
```

The `data = data[:-1]` is there to strip the delimiter sent through the websocket.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the error, please? Like data.__repr__() and the error, that is caught.

Comment: I did not now about __repr__(), that's amazing: `'\x00{"test":"test"}'`
The problem was in there, apparently there's a starting character too, but you can't see it in the console. Removing it fixed it.

Could you tell me how to get the error, though? I'm quite new to python's way of error handling, and I can't seem to print out ValueError as is.

Comment: It's "except ValueError, e:", I think. Then you can "print e".

Comment: the \x00 might be part of the websocket protocol's framing delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import traceback
try:
    d = json.loads(data[data.index('{'):-1])
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
else:
    print(d)
```

This way only the dictionary part of the data-string is parsed to json.loads().